# Delay on loop without locking the screen

Tags: java, android, loops, delay

I've been working on an app where I need to get the location of the device. The thing is, I want to try at least 5 or 10 times and I want a delay in between each try, in order to show a error message in the screen after each try (FailedLocationMSG). The reason why I want this delay is because some times it takes some time to the gps start working and get the actual location. I've tried so many things and I can't make it work. The idea is to have an interface similar to a 'terminal' where I will display a message (Error, trying again 1/5.. Error 2/5....) after each try. The problem is, I've tried using Handler and Thread.sleep but I always get my screen locked and I can't see the error message displayed on the screen after each try.

This is the method where I get the location:

```
int breakloop=0;
private void GetLocation(){

    locationmanager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria cri=new Criteria();
    String provider=locationmanager.getBestProvider(cri,false);

    if(provider!=null & !provider.equals("")){
        //Get location
        final Location location=locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,2000,10,this);


        while(breakloop<10){
            breakloop++;
            if(location!=null)
                onLocationChanged(location);
            else
                FailedLocationMSG(breakloop);
        }

    }else
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Provider is null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're facing? You only specified what you want to do, please add details about the exact problem.

Comment: I've tried using Handler and Thread.sleep but I always get my screen locked and I can't see the error message displayed on the screen after each try.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `FutureTask` and a `Callable` for your location check and wait for its return value.

```
public class LocationChecker implements Callable<Location> {
    @Override
    public Location call() throws Exception {
        //do your stuff for location check
        return location;
    }
}
```

in your method you do something like

```
LocationChecker lc = new LocationChecker();
FutureTask<Location> ft = new FutureTask<Location>(lc);
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
es.execute(ft);

Location loc;
int attempts = 0;
while(attempts < 10) {
    if(ft.isDone() && loc != null) {
        es.shutdown();
        break;
    }        
    else if(ft.isDone() && loc == null) {
        ft = new FutureTask<Location>(lc);
        es.execute(ft);
        attempts++;
    }

    loc = ft.get();
}
```

This will check your location and will wait for the result (ten times).